# Search webpart in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have created a document library with about 20 columns for storing meta data. The client wants to have search on this metadata with a facility to filter the data based on two values. For example we have two date columns(efective date and termination date) and the results that they wanted to see is files which are having the values between effective date and termination date.

Is there any out of the box solution that i can use for this or should i build a custom webpart. If so, can someone please guide me through....

Comment: This question would be better suited for your http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com account as it may or may not actually involve programming.

Answer (score 1):

Create your document library, then in "document library settings" click "Metadata Navigation Settings".

This should give you what you want. You can specify which columns to filter data on. You can stack the filters and by default they appear on the left of the page for users to interact with.